# Compare current row based from other rows

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a df

```
ID  Name   Value
0   A      10
1   A      11
3   A      15
4   B       7
5   B      11
C   X       1
```

I want to find, for the current row, count how many other rows has the same name and greater value.
Expected output;

```
ID  Name   Value  Res
0   A      10       2
1   A      11       1
3   A      15       0
4   B       7       1
5   B      11       0
6   X       1       0
```

Edit: Additional case. Only Include in count where tag=1

```
ID  Name   Value   Tag Res
0   A       9       1    2
1   A      10       0    2
2   A      11       1    1
3   A      15       1    0
4   B       7       1    1
5   B      11       1    0
6   X       1       1    0
```

Answer (score 3):

With a bit of tweaking, you could use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `method='dense'`:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby("Name")["Value"]
>>> df["Res"] = grouped.rank(method="dense", ascending=False).astype(int) - 1
>>> df
  ID Name  Value  Res
0  0    A     10    2
1  1    A     11    1
2  3    A     15    0
3  4    B      7    1
4  5    B     11    0
5  C    X      1    0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Seems that my data has additional case. I updated my question.